# Creating a variable depending on conditions using existing three columns

Tags: r

So each patient's outcome in the dataset are 1 if they were hospitalised; went into critical care; or died.

As below:

```r
ID       hosp       critical     death
1        1          1            1
2        1          NA           NA
3        NA         1            NA
4        NA         NA           1
5        NA         NA           NA
```

I want to use this information to create an "outcome" variable. If they had all three, but ultimately had 1 for death, their outcome should be "death". If they had been hospitalised and critical, their final outcome would be "critical". If they were hospitalised but did not go into critical, their outcome will be "severe". Lastly, if they were not admitted to anything, it will be "mild"

```r
ID       Outcome       
1        Death
2        Severe
3        Critical
4        Death
5        Mild
```

Comment: Your question suggest that if there is condition (hospitalised and critical) then Outcome should be "Critical", it follows that your ID#3 is wrong because it has only critical=1.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `case_when()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Outcome=case_when(death==1 ~ "Death",
                                critical==1 ~ "Critical",
                                hosp==1 ~ "Severe",
                                TRUE ~ "Mild"))
```

Then you can drop the original columns if you want. All in a single call:

```
df %>% mutate(Outcome=case_when(death==1 ~ "Death",
                                critical==1 ~ "Critical",
                                hosp==1 ~ "Severe",
                                TRUE ~ "Mild"))%>%
      select(-c(hosp, critical, death))
```

Comment: Instead of using `select` you could add `.keep = "unused"` into your `mutate`-statement.

Comment: Awesome, @Martin Gal, i did not know `.keep`, looks VERY USEFUL

Answer (score 2):

I will supply two solutions in the `tidyverse`, which both provide `Outcome` as an **ordered** `factor` that can be sorted by severity. They also permit easily customizable levels of severity.

Given your sample data, reproduced here as `statuses`

```
structure(list(ID       = c(1,  2,  3,  4,  5),
               hosp     = c(1,  1, NA, NA, NA),
               critical = c(1, NA,  1, NA, NA),
               death    = c(1, NA, NA,  1, NA)),
          row.names = c(NA, -5L),
          class = "data.frame")
```

here are the two solutions.

## Explicit Variables

When it's easy to explicitly name all "status variables" (`hosp` | `critical` | `death`) in `statuses`, this solution here will be quite handy:

```
library(tidyverse)


# ...
# Code to generate 'statuses'.
# ...


status_levels  <- c(          "hosp", "critical", "death")
#                           |------|  |--------|  |-----|
outcome_levels <- c("Mild", "Severe", "Critical", "Death")


outcomes <- statuses %>%
  # "Unpivot" the data.
  pivot_longer(cols = hosp:death) %>%
  # Convert the names of the "unpivoted" columns into the ordered levels that
  # were specified.
  mutate(name = ordered(name, levels = status_levels)) %>%
  # Aggregate to find the MAX (most severe) outcomes for every ID, and convert
  # them into the ordered levels that were specified.
  group_by(ID) %>% summarize(Outcome = ordered(outcome_levels, levels = outcome_levels)[max(as.integer(name) * !is.na(value)) + 1]) %>% ungroup()


# View results.
outcomes
```

**Note:** The `i`th level in `status_levels` (namely `status_levels[i]`) must map to the `(i + 1)`th level in `outcome_levels` (namely `outcome_levels[i + 1]`).

## Arbitrary Variables

If there were arbitrarily many status variables, it would be a hassle to explicitly name all those columns. As long as every column (besides `ID`) is a status variable, **ordered from left to right by increasing severity**, the following solution will always work*:

```
library(tidyverse)


# ...
# Code to generate 'statuses'.
# ...


outcome_levels <- c("Mild", "Severe", "Critical", "Death")


outcomes <- statuses %>%
  # "Unpivot" the data.
  pivot_longer(cols = !ID) %>%
  # Aggregate to find the last (most severe) outcomes for every ID, and convert
  # them into the ordered levels that were specified.
  group_by(ID) %>% summarize(Outcome = ordered(outcome_levels, levels = outcome_levels)[max(row_number() * !is.na(value)) + 1]) %>% ungroup()


# View results.
outcomes
```

* You will, of course, **need to update `outcome_levels`** appropriately to match the status variables; such that the `i`th status column maps to the `(i + 1)`th level in `outcome_levels`: namely `outcome_levels[i + 1]`.

## Results

Given the `statuses` dataset described above, each solution should yield the following result for `outcomes`:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     ID Outcome 
  <dbl> <ord>   
1     1 Death   
2     2 Severe  
3     3 Critical
4     4 Death   
5     5 Mild
```

Here the `Outcome` column is an ordered `factor`

```
[1] Death    Severe   Critical Death    Mild    
Levels: Mild < Severe < Critical < Death
```

that can be used to sort `outcomes` by severity

```
outcomes %>% arrange(Outcome)
```

to obtain this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     ID Outcome 
  <dbl> <ord>   
1     5 Mild    
2     2 Severe  
3     3 Critical
4     1 Death   
5     4 Death
```

Comment: TLDR so, in summary, you have a general approach with tidyr, and create ordered factors.

Comment: @GuedesBF Yup, though technically with the whole `tidyverse` rather than `tidyr` alone.  I kinda figured my first two sentences would serve as the TLDR: _"I will supply two solutions in the `tidyverse`, which both provide `Outcome` as an ordered `factor` that can be sorted by severity. They also permit easily customizable levels of severity."_

Comment: The pivot_longer approach is really nice.

Comment: @GuedesBF Thank you!  I was influenced by my earlier attempts to create a diagnostic paradigm for my R scripts, such that each diagnostic output (from `message()`, `warning()`, or `stop()`) was ranked numerically according to severity; and the final status of a run was given by `max()` operating on that numerical rank: the most severe diagnostic event.  Here, it applies to medical diagnoses!

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
df$outcome <- c("Mild", "Severe", "Critical", "Death")[
    rowSums(
        cbind(
            do.call(pmax, c(df[-1] * col(df[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)),
            1
        ),
        na.rm = TRUE
    )
]
```

gives

```
> df
  ID hosp critical death  outcome
1  1    1        1     1    Death
2  2    1       NA    NA   Severe
3  3   NA        1    NA Critical
4  4   NA       NA     1    Death
5  5   NA       NA    NA     Mild
```

Comment: Instead of instead of `c("Mild", "Severe", "Critical", "Death")`, why not use `ordered(c("Mild", "Severe", "Critical", "Death"), levels = c("Mild", "Severe", "Critical", "Death"))` to create the `outcome` as a `factor` sortable by severity?

Comment: @Greg I think the latter is sufficient to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This function will solve the problem:

```
myFun <- function(x) {
  outcome <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 5)
  colnames(outcome) <- "Outcome"
  for (i in 1:5) {
    if(!is.na(x[i,4])) outcome[i] <- "Death"
    else if(!is.na(x[i,2])) outcome[i] <- "Severe"
    else if(!is.na(x[i,3])) outcome[i] <- "Critical"
    else outcome[i] <- "Mild"
  }
  return(data.frame(outcome))
}
```

Output of `myFun(df)` where df is your data:

```
> myFun(df)
   Outcome
1    Death
2   Severe
3 Critical
4    Death
5     Mild
```